# ternary operators in return statement do not work in react useState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to to both understand and refactor my framework code from the business logic and I am getting into some confusion to why things are not working. At the moment I have managed to create a simply counter in react using the useState hook.

I am wanting to separate the code into parts so that in the future I can use them somewhere else and to keep my code tidy. The issue that I am having is that my ternary operators do not seem to be working in the refactored code and I am not sure why. for now I have only attempted to redo my increment values but this no longer is working I have commented out the old code as reference.

If anyone can give me any insight to what I have done wrong then this would be most helpfull. thank you.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Counter ()  {

    const shopProps = {
        quantity: 0,
        message: null,
        max: 10,
        min: 0
    }


    const [state, setState] = useState(shopProps)

    // this is the new function but the ternary operation no longer works.

    function increase({previousQuantity, max}) {
        console.log(previousQuantity)
        return {
            message: previousQuantity < max ? null : "Max!",
            quantity: previousQuantity < max ? previousQuantity + 1 : max
        };
    }

    function increment() {
        // accepts the argument of a the prevState
        setState(prevState =>
            increase({...prevState,
                previousQuantity:prevState.quantity,
                max: prevState.max})
        );
    };

    //the old function that worked before refactor.

    /*function increment() {
        // accepts the argument of a the prevState
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            quantity: prevState.quantity < prevState.max ? prevState.quantity + 1 : prevState.max,
            message: prevState.quantity < prevState.max ? null : 'Max!!'
        }))
    }*/

    function decrement() {
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            quantity: prevState.quantity > prevState.min ? prevState.quantity - 1 : prevState.min,
            message: prevState.quantity > prevState.min ? null : 'Min!!'
        }))

    }

    function reset(){
        setState(prevState => ({...prevState, quantity: 0}))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Count: {state.quantity}</p>
            <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={decrement}>decrement</button>
            <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>
            <div>{state.message}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Counter;
```

Comment: "*my ternary operators do not seem to be working*" not working how? What's happening? What's supposed to be happening?

Comment: @VLAZ the conditional arguments that are in the increase function are not being returned and resulting in no value being shown at all. before i changed my code this method was working. So I have done something wrong but not where i have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you mean by the conditional operator "not working" it's hard to be sure what's wrong, but the thing that jumps out is that your `increase` function only returns an object with `message` and `quantity`:

```
function increase({previousQuantity, max}) {
    console.log(previousQuantity)
    return {
        message: previousQuantity < max ? null : "Max!",
        quantity: previousQuantity < max ? previousQuantity + 1 : max
    };
}
```

...but your `increment` function is using it to **completely replace** your `state` object:

```
function increment() {
    // accepts the argument of a the prevState
    setState(prevState =>                           // ***
        increase({...prevState,                     // ***
            previousQuantity:prevState.quantity,    // ***
            max: prevState.max})                    // ***
    );                                              // ***
}; // <=== Side note: No reason for this `;`
```

That means any properties other than `message` and `quantity` will get wiped out.

When you're using hooks, you usually don't want a single state object, but rather individual state members, like this:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
// ...
```

That kind of modularity helps keep the code simple.

But if you want to keep your current all-in-one-object state, be sure that you preserve the other properties:

```
function increment() {
    // accepts the argument of a the prevState
    setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        ...increase({
            previousQuantity: prevState.quantity,
            max: prevState.max
        })
    });
}
```

---

For what it's worth, here's that component using discrete state members; see comments:

```
// These aren't state, so declare them once outside the component function
const MAX_QUANTITY = 10;
const MIN_QUANTITY = 0;

function Counter()  {

    // These are state
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

    // I don't really see a point to the `increase` function, so didn't do it

    function increment() {
        // No particular reason to use the callback version here, you're re-creating
        // the function every time
        if (quantity < MAX_QUANTITY) {
            setMessage(null);
            setQuantity(quantity + 1);
        } else {
            setMessage("Max!");
        }
    }

    function decrement() {
        // ...similar to increment...
    }

    function reset() {
        setQuantity(0);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Count: {quantity}</p>
            <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={decrement}>decrement</button>
            <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>
            <div>{message}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I was just referring to how my current rendition of the code was no longer working, like it did before due to my destructing and lack of understanding. I have learnt two things today, simplicity and what things should be put in state. thx :)